# What is the best method to find a class/property in c# through reflection after obfuscation has been done?

Tags: c#, reflection, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Here's an example of the code which will be used for the reflection:

```
var i = typeof(Program).Assembly.CreateInstance("test.Program");
```

After the software is obfuscated, the code will obviously stop working.

I'm trying to find a way around it by searching for properties of a class, which do not change after obfuscation has been done. I've tried that with type.GUID, but when I run the debug version, I get one GUID, and in the release after the obfuscation is completed, the guid is changed.

I'm using Eazfuscator.NET for obfuscation.

I would like to avoid using attributes to mark class/method if possible.

Any ideas on what would work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the motivation to avoid using attributes to mark classes and methods?

Comment: I am always confused by people who ask the question "I want to do X, but I want to avoid the easy and obvious solution, and I'm not going to tell you why."  We are not psychic; if you have a reason to avoid an obvious solution like "mark it with an attribute to skip obfuscation", we sure don't know what that reason is. Presumably you don't just enjoy the challenge of doing things the hard way.

Comment: Moreover, the question is a bit self-defeating. You want to use an obfuscator, presumably to defeat your attackers, but you want it to be weak enough that you can defeat it. If you can find a way to reliably defeat the obfuscator then you should not rely upon it to protect you from whatever attack it is you are worried about!

Comment: I don't want the obfuscator to defeat the attackers. Just make the job of understanding the code more difficult. And I want this as a part of advanced piracy protection

Comment: @Arsen Still keeping the reason for not wanting to use attributes to yourself then?

Comment: @chibacity:It signals to the person who's looking at the code in reflector that there's something special about this class/method

Comment: Are you sure a string is more hiding than an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> don't want the obfuscator to defeat the attackers. Just make the job of understanding the code more difficult. And I want this as a part of advanced piracy protection

After obfuscation; zip, encrypt and do whatever you want with your assembly. Then create another wrapper project and add your assembly as a resource into that project. Attach to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event (in your new project) and whenever an unresolved assembly event occurs, read your resource(decrypt,unzip etc.) and return the actual assembly.

You may also try to obfuscate your final wrapper application.

How secure? At least, you can make life more harder for attackers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are ways to iterate over all types and find the one you're looking for, but the things that come to mind would all produce the least maintainable code ever.

Some obfuscators (we use DeepSea, I don't know Eazfuscator) allow preventing obfuscation of specific classes, allowing reflection on those. In DeepSea's case, this is indicated by attributes but those won't/shouldn't (I never checked :o) make it to the final assembly.

If you regard reflection as "an outside process looking at your assembly" and obfuscating "preventing outside processes from looking at your assembly" you're really stopping yourself from doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have exact answer, but [ILSpy](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/danielgrunwald/archive/2011/02/04/ilspy-a-new-net-assembly-inspector.aspx)'s source might help you.